# Why os.listdir() finds the excel but pd.read_excel() returns error?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, windows, jupyter-notebook, listdir

here is the simple version of my code:

```
for filename in os.listdir('excels/'):
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df.head()
```

Output is:

```
RandomExcelData.xlsx
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'RandomExcelData.xlsx'
```

What is really happening here? why pandas does not recognize the file name that is clearly there?

I tested this and it works properly:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excels/RandomExcelData.xlsx')
df.head()
```

this returns output as intended...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting this result because `filename` is just the filename, not the full path. Try this line instead:

```
df = pd.read_excel('excels/' + filename)
```

Or, change the script's working directory to `'excels'`:

```
for filename in os.listdir('excels/'):
    print(filename)
    os.chdir('excels')
    df = pd.read_excel(filename)
    df.head()
```

Comment: really appreciated, did know I can change directory in the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the path when reading the Excel files:

```
for filename in os.listdir('excels/'):
    print(filename)
    df = pd.read_excel('excels/' + filename)
    df.head()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
directory = 'data/'

files = [os.path.join(directory, file) for file in os.listdir(directory) if file.endswith('.csv')]

for file in files:
    df = pd.read_csv(file)
```